# How to express type bound that forces the type param to behave like functor

Tags: scala, types, scala-cats

I'm struggling to write a method that operates on either Free Monad to Tagles Final. I would like to use type class to pass an interpreter that produces a Monad. In the same function I would like to use `map` function.

I don't know how to express type bound so that the M type is a functor or monad.

```
import cats._
import cats.free.Free

def eval[M[_]](param: String)(implicit op: Algebra ~> M): M[String] {
  val program: Free[Algebra, String] = Free.liftF(Operation(param))
  Free.foldMap(op)
}

def process[M[_]](param: String)(implicit op: Algebra ~> M): M[String] {
   val result = eval(param)
   result.map(_.toUpper) //this doesn't compile because M is missing map method
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `eval[M[_]: Monad]` or `eval[M[_]: Functor]`?

Comment: Maybe you also need `import cats.syntax.functor._` or
`import cats.syntax.monad._`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
import cats.{Monad, ~>}
import cats.free.Free
import cats.syntax.functor._

import scala.language.higherKinds

trait Algebra[_]

case class Operation(str: String) extends Algebra[String]

def eval[M[_]: Monad](param: String)(implicit op: Algebra ~> M): M[String] = {
  val program: Free[Algebra, String] = Free.liftF (Operation (param) )
  Free.foldMap(op).apply(program)
}

def process[M[_]: Monad](param: String)(implicit op: Algebra ~> M): M[String] = {
  val result = eval(param)
  result.map(_.toUpperCase)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I started with, but I was missing the import: cats.syntax.functor._

Comment: @BartoszJankiewicz, if the answer helps, you should accept it. If it doesn't - it makes sense to point out what exactly is wrong.